# Getting error while running jsp file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat6

I have created a simple Hello.jsp program in my eclipse(juno).When I tried to run this jsp file by run on server,getting below error

problem occurred,

'Publishing to Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost' has encoured a problem
Publishing failed with multiple errors
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30730.jsp.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30731.MF.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30732.xml.

In the error log, getting the below details

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core 4 0 2013-12-11 22:46:11.654
!MESSAGE Publishing failed with multiple errors
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-12-11 22:46:11.654
!MESSAGE Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30730.jsp.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-12-11 22:46:11.654
!MESSAGE Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30731.MF.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-12-11 22:46:11.654
!MESSAGE Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp30732.xml.

I have deleted eclipse & tomcat server, then reinstalled again. But still getting the same error.I tried by selecting server location as use custom location and giving different workspace path. But nothing works.

I'm using eclipse Juno, apache tomcat-v6.0.37, jdk 1.6

Can anyone please help me on this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: You've made sure you have no filesystem errors or permission problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new eclipse workspace in another directory and kept the server also inside the workspace. Now it is working for me.The solution is we should have the server and eclipse workspace in same file system.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those worked for me.  I deleted the temp folder from my tomcat installation and removed also the project folder (the one that was causing the problem) from the wtpweapps folder, and it worked.